# App won't launch next activity and Crash

Tags: java, android

I want to press my Table Topics button to launch the Table Topics Activity and it ended up crashing the app but my code looks everything perfectly fine to me, I hope you guys can help me what's going on with my code. The Timing button used to work to launch other Activity but now I added the code for the Table Topics it just crash everything if I press any of the buttons

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.iprex.light;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void onClickGreen(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.iprex.green"));

}

public void onClickYellow(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.iprex.yellow"));

}

public void onClickRed(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.iprex.red"));

}

public void onClickTBTWhite(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.iprex.tbtwhite"));

}

}
```

This is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.iprex.light">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Green" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.green"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Yellow" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.yellow"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Red" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.red"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TBTWhite" android:label="Times">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.tbtwhite"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TBTGreen" android:label="Times">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.tbtgreen"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TBTYellow" android:label="Times">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.tbtyellow"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TBTRed" android:label="Times">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.iprex.tbtred"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

This is the run log after I press the button

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.iprex.light, PID: 20558
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207) 
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 
               Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.iprex.tbtwhite launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1839)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1531)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4389)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4348)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:711)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4672)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4640)
                  at com.iprex.light.MainActivity.onClickTBTWhite(MainActivity.java:40)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207) 
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: plz show your log cat output when crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to start other activities is not correct. Change your code to

```
public void onClickGreen(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Green.class));
}

public void onClickYellow(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Yellow.class));
}

public void onClickRed(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Red.class));
}

public void onClickTBTWhite(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, TBTWhite.class));
}
```

If you want to start other activities with package name and class name. Then you can try

```
public void onClickGreen(View view) {
    openActivity("com.iprex.green", "com.iprex.green.Green");
}

public void onClickYellow(View view) {
    openActivity("com.iprex.yellow", "com.iprex.yellow.Yellow");
}

public void onClickRed(View view) {
    openActivity("com.iprex.red", "com.iprex.red.Green");
}

public void onClickTBTWhite(View view){
    openActivity("com.iprex.tbtwhiten", "com.iprex.tbtwhite.TBTWhite");
}

private void openActivity(String packageName, String className) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can apply above code to other activities

Happy coding!

Comment: I'm still wondering how are you able to solve the code of errors in matter of minutes, It's amazing on how you solve mine and I'm still shock by it :) @sontruongit

Comment: In your case there are 2 possible root causes. The first is you forgot to register your activities in manifest file. The second is your code to start the activities are not correct. As the result your case is the second one. It's not amazing just from my experiences :)